# How do I save the values of select options field and checkboxes in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have checkboxes and select options fields but the values are not saving. Here's the code:

The checkbox:

```
<label>
  <input name='gradeeleven'
   value={'Grade Eleven'}
   type='checkbox'
   checked={props.gradeeleven === 'Grade Eleven'}
   onChange={handleChange}
   required
   />
   Grade Eleven
</label>
```

And the select option field:

```
<label>Position</label>

   <select>
     <option value={props['principal']} name='position' onChange={handleChange} key={1}>Principal</option>
     <option value={props['viceprincipal']} name='position' onChange={handleChange} key={2}>Vice Principal</option>
     <option value={props['teacher']} name='position' onChange={handleChange} key={3}>Teacher</option>
     <option value={props['registrar']} name='position' onChange={handleChange} key={4}>Registrar</option>
     <option value={props['administrator']} name='position' onChange={handleChange} key={5}>Administrator</option>
  </select>
```

I'm doing similar thing for radio button and it's working but I don't understanding why these are not working.

Here an example of my radio button:

```
<label>
   <input name='sex'
   value={'Female'}
   type='radio'
   checked={props.sex === 'Female'}
   key={2}
   onChange={handleChange}
   required
   />
   Female
</label>
```

By the way, I'm currently saving them in localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

So you can create some state variables and then when you call your handleChange() method, that time you set the state of those variables using setState() and then when you want to send them to your backend using ajax call you can send using this.state.variable_name.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In case of checkbox, you are settig a checked attribute and also a `handleChange` function, so what ever the function returns, your checkbox will always be `checked` or `unchecked` depending on the props, same is the case with radio button. Use `defaultChecked` instead and then set the checked property with state

You should handle it like

```
<label>
  <input name='gradeeleven'
   value='Grade Eleven'
   type='checkbox'
   defaultChecked={props.gradeeleven === 'Grade Eleven'}
   checked={this.state.gradeeleven} 
   onChange={handleChange}
   required
   />
   Grade Eleven
</label>
```

or better even

```
<label>
  <input name='gradeeleven'
   value='Grade Eleven'
   type='checkbox'

   checked={this.state.gradeeleven} 
   onChange={handleChange}
   required
   />
   Grade Eleven
</label>


componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({gradeeleven: (this.props.gradeeleven === 'Grade Eleven')? true: false})
}
handleChange(e) {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({gradeeleven: !prevState.gradeeleven}));
}
```

for the select function have and onChange on the select, rather than the options fields

```
<label>Position</label>

   <select onChange={handleChange}>
     <option value={props['principal']} name='position' key={1}>Principal</option>
     <option value={props['viceprincipal']} name='position' key={2}>Vice Principal</option>
     <option value={props['teacher']} name='position' key={3}>Teacher</option>
     <option value={props['registrar']} name='position' key={4}>Registrar</option>
     <option value={props['administrator']} name='position' key={5}>Administrator</option>
  </select>

 handleChange(e) {
      console.log(e.target.value)
  }
```